# Difficult Gaussian Integral Involving Two Trig Functions in the Exponent: Any Help?

Tags: calculus, integration

Here's the integral:

> $$\int_d^e \exp\left(-a\left((b+c)\cos(x)-\sqrt{b^2 - (b+c)^2 \sin^2(x)}\right)^2 \right) \, dx$$

I've tried using Mathematica: it fails.

Can anyone help evaluate it?

Perhaps some kind of series expansion of the exponential might help...
Have any of you dealt with these kinds of Gaussians before?

Offering Respect,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $b\neq0$ , $c\neq0$ and $b+c\neq0$ to maintain the key meaning of the question.

$\int_d^e\exp\left(-a\left((b+c)\cos x-\sqrt{b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x}\right)^2 \right)~dx$

$=\int_d^e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^na^n\left((b+c)\cos x-\sqrt{b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x}\right)^{2n}}{n!}dx$

$=\int_d^e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nC_{2m}^{2n}a^n(b+c)^{2n-2m}\cos^{2n-2m}x\left(\sqrt{b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x}\right)^{2m}}{n!}dx-\int_d^e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^nC_{2m-1}^{2n}a^n(b+c)^{2n-2m+1}\cos^{2n-2m+1}x\left(\sqrt{b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x}\right)^{2m-1}}{n!}dx$

$=\int_d^e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!a^n(b+c)^{2n-2m}\cos^{2n-2m}x\left(b^2-(b+c)^2+(b+c)^2\cos^2x\right)^m}{n!(2m)!(2n-2m)!}dx-\int_d^e\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{m=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!a^n(b+c)^{2n-2m+1}\cos^{2n-2m+1}x\left(b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x\right)^{m-\frac{1}{2}}}{n!(2m-1)!(2n-2m+1)!}dx$

Note that both $\int\cos^{2n-2m}x\left(b^2-(b+c)^2+(b+c)^2\cos^2x\right)^m~dx$ and $\int\cos^{2n-2m+1}x\left(b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x\right)^{m-\frac{1}{2}}~dx$ , where $m$ and $n$ are any non-negative integers have close-form.

Comment: Thanks for this - I managed to simplify the original integral a bit, getting rid of the square in the exponent, but this method still applies. Cheers :)

Comment: Can I just use mathematica to find the closed form expressions you mention?

Comment: You can try to calculate $\int\cos^{2n-2m}x\left(b^2-(b+c)^2+(b+c)^2\cos^2x\right)^m~dx$ and $\int\cos^{2n-2m+1}x\left(b^2-(b+c)^2\sin^2x\right)^{m-\frac{1}{2}}~dx$ by mathematica by yourself, but it is important that you should try your best to restrict $m$ and $n$ as non-negative integers as the inputs on mathematica, otherwise mathematica will treat $m$ and $n$ as complex number and get the output in terms of special function.

Comment: I used wolfram alpha and got an answer in terms of a hypergeometric sereis - does this sound right or can I find a simpler expression?