# Is this integral undefined

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\arcsin(g/r)}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\left((a)\cos^{2n-2m}(x)(g^{2}-r^{2}+r^{2}\cos^{2}(x))^{m}\right)\right)\,dx$$
where $$a=\frac{(-1)^{n}(2n)!v^{n}r^{2n-2m}}{n!(2m)!(2n-2m)!},$$
which comes out to
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\left((a)(\phi)\right),$$
where
$$\phi=\left[\varphi(\cos^{2}(x))^{\frac{1}{2}+m-n}\sin(x)(g^{2}-r^{2}\sin^{2}(x))^{m}\left(1-\frac{r^{2}\sin^{2}(x)}{g^{2}}\right)^{-m}\right]_{0}^{\arcsin(g/r)}$$
and
$$\varphi=\operatorname{AppellF1}\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+m-n,-m,\frac{3}{2},\sin^{2}(x),\frac{r^{2}\sin^{2}x}{g^{2}}\right]\cos^{-1-2m+2n}(x),$$
which all comes from [Difficult Gaussian Integral Involving Two Trig Functions in the Exponent: Any Help?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459107/difficult-gaussian-integral-involving-two-trig-functions-in-the-exponent-any-he/459804#459804)

However, when I evaluate this at the upper limit I get terms in the sum that involve
$$\left(1-\frac{r^{2}\sin^{2}(\arcsin(g/r))}{g^{2}}\right)^{-m}=(0)^{-m}$$
with $m$ climbing up so that we have terms in the integral that are undefined ($0^{-a}$ is undefinied for positive $a$).

Does this mean the integral cannot be done between these limits? I'm trying to plot the sum for various $g$ and $r$ but Matlab keeps giving me NaN's due to the $0^{-1}$ terms.

Thanks.

Comment: In your definition of $a$ the term $a^n$ appears, wth?

Comment: sorry, used a variable twice, have a look again: can I simplify the 4th expression, merging the final terms?

Comment: It may help to reindex your sums. You can try swapping $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^n$ with $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=m}^\infty$. Then you could replace all instances of $n$ in the expression with $n+m$, and be left with a sum $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty$. Your expression has lots of "$n-m$" in it, so this change would simplify the appearance of the expression and may make it separable.