# Tricky Gaussian; a good method?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone help evaluate

$$
\int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{r+\epsilon-\sqrt{r^{2}-x^{2}}}e^{-\beta\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)} \, dy \, dx
$$

($r$ and $\epsilon$ are constants)?

Comment: I feel that you should use polar co-ordinates.

Comment: so just replace x = rcos(theta) and y = rsin(theta) and then try it? (plus rdrd(theta))

Comment: Yes. But you have to transform the limits, which would lead to integrals of non elementary functions. But give it a go and post your workings for others to see.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. You get a tricky Gaussian similar to my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459107/difficult-gaussian-integral-involving-two-trig-functions-in-the-exponent-any-he. Any other ideas?

Comment: I will have a look. But if no one has posted an answer yet it suggests it is very tricky indeed. Is there a need to get an analytical answer? If not use numerical integration?

Comment: Need an analytic answer...