# Integral of a Gaussian Function over a complicated Region (based on the lower semicircle) - with picture?

Tags: integration, geometry, definite-integrals

OK,

I need the integral of

$$
f(x,y)=e^{-\beta\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}
$$

(beta is a constant)

over this green region, where we integrate from the origin outwards.

[image]

Any help? I tried in [Tricky Gaussian; a good method?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673040/tricky-gaussian-a-good-method), but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be evaluated explicitly.  The integral is easy enough to set up:

$$\int_{-r}^r dx \, e^{-\beta x^2} \, \int_0^{a+r-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}} dy \, e^{-\beta y^2}$$

which may be expressed as a single integral:

$$\frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}} \int_{-r}^r dx \, e^{-\beta x^2} \operatorname*{erf}{\left [ \sqrt{\beta} \left ( a+r-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\right )\right ]}$$

You can do a sub $x=r \cos{\theta}$, but it is unclear to me how this results in anything more useful.

Comment: I have got this far. Comment on this: If I sub u=x/r, getting an integral between 0 and 1 (if I cut things in half), is it possible to approximate the integral by expanding the integrand at 0 (which might be accurate enough between the limits)? Of course this is possible, but will it be accurate enough to be considered a good approximation? Hmmm...

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78615/integrating-a-product-of-exponentials-and-error-functions?rq=1, it might help, though arranging things such that we can make things simpler this way seems non-trivial...

Comment: @AlexanderGiles: you could, but my gut tells me that this is not going to get you very much accuracy for the effort.  I would just do a simple numerical quadrature, as erf and the gaussian make for a simple, smooth function.

Comment: can't use numerical intergration - need a result or approximation for small a.

Comment: Perhaps the second answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78615/integrating-a-product-of-exponentials-and-error-functions?rq=1 could help?